# Executing extra code inside setState callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am executing extra code to send a webSocket message inside the setState callback, and I want to know if what I am doing is correct or can lead to some problems. this is what I have:

```js
const setLocalMessageData = (body: string, sendMessage: SendMessage) => {
  setMessagesData((messages) => {
    const number = messages.length
    sendMessage(number, body)
    const message = {user: LOCAL_USER, number: number, body: body, ack: false}
    return [...messages, message]
  })
}
```

setMessagesData is the setState and sendMessage is the extra code that transmits a webSocket message.

I expect that te setLocalMessageData transmits the webSocket message and update messagesData properly.

Comment: ```messages``` variable contains previous state data. The better way is using ```useEffect```

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the other answers posted here; a `useEffect()` should *not* be introduced here. This is due to a couple of reasons which are covered thoroughly in the new React docs.

The first is that in React [StrictMode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode), [effects are run twice](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-re-running-effects-in-development), meaning during development, an effect would send two messages instead of just one. This can lead to unpredictable and unintended behavior during development. While this can be fixed with the appropriate cleanup function, there is another issue.

The other reason is that effects are a tool for [synchronizing your component with an **external** system](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#:%7E:text=Effects%20let%20you%20run%20some%20code%20after%20rendering%20so%20that%20you%20can%20synchronize%20your%20component%20with%20some%20system%20outside%20of%20React.). However, the user isn't external; if you want something to happen because the user did something, then that logic should be in an event handler, not `useEffect()`. Event handlers are guaranteed to only execute in response to some user interaction. You can read more about situations in which you don't need an effect [here](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect).

Moreover, React batches state updates. So if something were to update your messages list with multiple new messages, `useEffect` would only send the most recent `body` through your WebSocket, not all new messages.

And finally, if you are planning to implement receiving messages from the WebSocket, then updating the array with the received message would cause the `useEffect` to send the last message it received back through WebSocket, potentially creating an infinite message loop between clients.

Therefore, I recommend you simply define a new function within your component to be your event handler, and send the message within it like so:

```
// use this instead of wherever `setLocalMessageData()` was being called.
function submitMessage() {
  const messageCount = messages.length;
  const newMessage = {user: LOCAL_USER, number: number, body, ack: false};
  setMessagesData(messages => [...messages, newMessage]);
  
  sendMessage(messageCount, body);
}
```

Also, to clarify the issue with your initial approach: React expects `set` functions to be pure (have no side effects), so [it also calls them twice](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development:%7E:text=Functions%20that%20you%20pass%20to%20useState%2C%20set%20functions%2C%20useMemo%2C%20or%20useReducer) during development when in StrictMode, which would cause your message to get sent twice as well.

---

**EDIT**: If this component is handling receiving messages from the WebSocket as well, then there potentially may be a race condition where a new message might come in at the same time (in the same event loop iteration) that the user is sending one themselves. However, if the received messages are handled first, then `messages.length` in the other handler will not refer to the correct number of messages because React has not had the chance to rerender yet.

In this situation, I think it's best to declare a `Ref` in your component for synchronously accessing and updating the number of total messages (thanks [@Emile Bergeron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218980/emile-bergeron)). It should look roughly something like the following:

```
function SomeComponent() {
  const [messages, setMessagesData] = useState([]);
  const syncCount = useRef(messages.length);
  syncCount.current = messages.length; // sync with true state
  // ...

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleOnMessage = (evt) => {
      const newMessages = getNewMessages(evt.data);
      setMessagesData((messages) => [...messages, ...newMessages]);
      syncCount.current += newMessages.length;
    };

    socket.addEventListener("message", handleOnMessage);

    return () => {
      socket.removeEventListener("message", handleOnMessage);
    };
  }, []);
  // ...

  function submitMessage() {
    const newMessage = {user: LOCAL_USER, number: number, body, ack: false};
    setMessagesData(messages => [...messages, newMessage]);
    sendMessage(syncCount.current, body);
    syncCount.current += 1;
  }
  // ...
}
```

For reference, [here is a CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sync-event-handlers-tuz37c?file=/src/App.js) which recreates the race condition, and implements the described fix.

However, in my honest opinion, it seems a bit strange to me that you are sending the message's index over the WebSocket; I feel it's unnecessary. The server which manages the WebSockets should be the source of truth for the message data and its order. In other words, clients should not be asserting what they think the order of messages is to the server, but rather the server should be communicating to clients the order of messages (most likely based on the timestamp the messages were received by the server). That way, your React code doesn't need to worry about race conditions anymore because any uncertainty or inconsistency is resolved by the server.

Comment: number need to be the index of the message in the array, I did put sendMessage inside the setMessagesData callback because to ensure that.

Comment: The length of the array is going to be one more than the last index. As a result, when you add a new message to the end of the array, it’s index will be the length of the previous array. So my provided code will send it correctly.

Comment: setMessagesData is also called when receiving messages, and so could happen (I am not sure) that messagesData is updated after number = messages.lenght, and this number will not be the index in the array.

Comment: Assuming you aren’t memoizing the function, it should get redefined every time your state changes and you rerender. As a result, even if you update the messages array on receiving new messages, `submitMessage()` will always use the next index in the array.

Comment: but if before redefined the submitMessage react scheduled a second setMessageData ?.  That can happen?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. You are asking how to handle the race condition in which a new message is received in the same event loop iteration that a new message is being sent. While that is very unlikely, I guess it might be possible. I will update my answer with a workaround.

Comment: `messageCount` in the Edited part of this answer should probably be a state or a ref so that it keeps the count in-between renders. And the event listener should be setup inside an effect, otherwise, it would register a new listener every render and never unregister any of them.

Comment: @EmileBergeron You’re right about wrapping the event listener registration in an effect; I was just a bit lazy and trying to make a different point. And you’re right that `messageCount` should most likely be a `Ref` because it will work even if the reference becomes stale. However it’s important to reassign the ref to the count on every render to ensure it’s synchronized with the true state. I will show this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should rewrite it in this way:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const number = messages.length;

  sendMessage(number, body);
}, [messages]);
```

Comment: I don't think this is the right reason to introduce a `useEffect`. Check out my answer, it's based on recommendations from the new official React documentation. I'm open to discussion if you disagree.